# How to stop misuse of JWT Token

Tags: php, jwt, token, bearer-token

I am trying to use JWT for first time in API. API will be used by android & ios app. For that i have done below:

1. App will call my Login API, after verification of email & password system will return the appropriate response. API also returns the jwt_token which user will use to call further API.

## Request:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost/jwt/api/web/v1/login \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'device_token: 33B6A2799381556A2F4FBCA28EF3D' \
  -H 'device_type: 1' \
  -F email=test@test.com \
  -F password=123456
```

## Response

```
{
    "status": 201,
    "message": "Login success.",
    "result": {
        "jwt_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjRmMWcyM2ExMmFhIn0.eyJpc3MiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJhdWQiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJqdGkiOiI0ZjFnMjNhMTJhYSIsInZlcnNpb24iOiIxLjAiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzM3MzcxMzIsImV4cCI6MTU3Mzc0MDczMiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MiwidW5pcXVlX2NvZGUiOiJYWFhYWFgifQ.Jx1sw0y0c3D_rSGpvdiXSyHOHr8ioykOHxMMGYWnzIhD0XwrdLC7cqLEpU6cOUKMyrxvv-j1-d6u7R80ux7zPw"
    }
}
```

After that i have one more API which will be used to deduct the points

2. App will call deduct point api, For that sysetm will first verify the JWT Token and if its valid then it will deduct the point.
   Request
   ==

```
curl -X POST \
  http://192.168.1.109/jwt/api/web/v1/deduct-points \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjRmMWcyM2ExMmFhIn0.eyJpc3MiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJhdWQiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJqdGkiOiI0ZjFnMjNhMTJhYSIsInZlcnNpb24iOiIxLjAiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzM3MzcxMzIsImV4cCI6MTU3Mzc0MDczMiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MiwidW5pcXVlX2NvZGUiOiJYWFhYWFgifQ.Jx1sw0y0c3D_rSGpvdiXSyHOHr8ioykOHxMMGYWnzIhD0XwrdLC7cqLEpU6cOUKMyrxvv-j1-d6u7R80ux7zPw' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'device_token: 33B6A2799381556A2F4FBCA28EF3D' \
  -H 'device_type: 1' \
  -F points=100 \
```

## Response

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Your points deducted successfully.",
    "result": []
}
```

Now what i understand is if any how some one will get hold of my jwt_token then they will not able to change the data of that token. If they will system rejects that token. So far so good.

But now assume, attacker doesn't change any thing in my Token and simply calls my API as it is. In that case system will validate the JWT Token and deduct the points of user. So what should i do to resolve this issue?

Comment: What mechanism do you envisage via which someone would be able to get hold of the token but not, say, the original email/password combination?  IE what attack vector are you attempting to defend against?

Comment: You should safekeep your tokens (especially true for refresh tokens). Your tokens are like passwords - you don't share them.

Comment: @JamesThorpe We have a requirement in which third party website will call our API. For that there will be one button (Get Data From X) and click of that button third party will call our API in which we will return them a Token. After that they are going to call our Deduct Point API. So if there system compromise, my token can be misused.

Comment: Your problem is more likely: "How to mitigate MITM (man in the middle) attack". Jwt token only protects you from the modification of this data. If you want to be also protected from MITMAs (additionaly from SSL), you should implement some challenge generation&validation, and also append it in you JWT token.

Comment: Presumably the 3rd party website has to authenticate also - are you not worried about them also losing the original credentials used to create the token? Or is there a mechanism in place for your users to hand over a token to that website? Ultimately you probably need a way to expire tokens, and you either check a token's validity on every request, or you have short lived tokens and a refresh mechanism, whereby you invalidate the token for the next refresh - the token in the wild will then only work until it expires.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Actually, both Party shares one common unique code and using that we will generate the code. Also we have token expiry in place.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes system will have https.

Comment: ok fair enough removed that comment..

Comment: but still you have the remember that JWT is only safe, how safe your signing password is. If the attacker can reverse crack your signing password he/she can become any account on your server .. I extended JWA (JSON Web Algorithms) myself with bcrypt/argon as those are designed to be slow on CPU and GPU, making CPU/GPU bruteforces not possible and or precalculated rainbow tables not possible..  Also there is verify function in the [PHP Safe Password Hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) to safely compare password hashes without making it prone to timing attacks on the hash.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have used the Public-Private key to generate and verify the Token.

Comment: *" I have used the Public-Private key to generate and verify the Token."* i know i already saw that you used RS256 ,,, `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjRmMWcyM2ExMmFhIn0` -> `{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","jti":"4f1g23a12aa"}`  .. only hope that key is alteast 6800-bit which is more or less required/considerd to be save nowadays with RSA..-> https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/how-big-an-rsa-key-is-considered-secure-today/1982   Note: to design a system that will be used for 30 years, and the data must be kept secure for 20 years after it has first been processed. ..

Comment: So looks like i might have to invalidate token after each use and provide the new token. Also set small expiry time.

Comment: i think i modify the code to store public/private keys in a RDMS (maybe SQLite and store that file outside the webdir) and change the nature how that key is generated and verified with cryptographically safe functions like PHP 7 random_bytes() so that signing password is different for every JWT token,. Also be sure to keep a archive of old public/private keys to disallow a private key which was generated in the past (it can happen on some OS still a (very) small risk but still) and force a regen .. And yes add a expiry time would also increase security..

Comment: But when doing this be very very sure that there is no SQL injection in the PHP code somewhere or local file inclusion with (`php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=<file>`) where the attack could read a config file to possibly know the RDMS username and password and or find other prone things in your PHP code..   As that `php://filter` [PHP wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) thing is pure evil as some functions which you might not expect have support for this, which makes it even more worse i believe you can't even disable it with configuration.....

Comment: @RaymondNijland We are not storing the DB credentials on code level. We are not storing credentials on code level, it stored on aws KMS and ec2 server have permission to access the parameters from KMS.

Comment: *"We are not storing credentials on code level, it stored on aws KMS"* Does not matter then still that local file inclusion then is bad for security if they can read the complete PHP source code and find any  prone code to  upload a PHP (backdoor) file it is **game over** anyway..